# How to prevent Chrome to redirecting AJAX requests to HTTPS?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cors, preflight

My AngularJS application is doing many AJAX requests to our services (powered by Jetty). For some reason the following error occurs for SOME users only and goes away when asked to clear the browser cache. This **only happens on Google Chrome**.

I'm on www.domain.com trying to request api.domain.com.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.domain.com/my-service. The
>   request was redirected to 'https://api.domain.com/my-service', which
>   is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
>   /my-current-page

Note that Chrome is **trying to redirect the service from HTTP to HTTPS**. My website can be accessed over HTTP or HTTPS

Here is the chrome://net-internals/#events output:

```
1523417: URL_REQUEST
http://api.domain.com/my-service
Start Time: 2014-08-15 14:17:39.809

t=5984 [st= 0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=26]
t=5984 [st= 0]   +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=5984 [st= 0]      DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=0]
                    --> delegate_info = "extension AdBlock"
t=5984 [st= 0]      DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=0]
                    --> delegate_info = "extension AdBlock"
t=5984 [st= 0]   -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=5984 [st= 0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=26]
                  --> load_flags = 143540480 (DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES | DO_NOT_SEND_AUTH_DATA | DO_NOT_SEND_COOKIES | ENABLE_LOAD_TIMING | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                  --> method = "OPTIONS"
                  --> priority = "LOW"
                  --> url = "http://api.domain.com/my-service"
t=5984 [st= 0]      URL_REQUEST_REDIRECT_JOB
                    --> reason = "HSTS"
t=5985 [st= 1]     +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=25]
t=5985 [st= 1]        DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=25]
                      --> delegate_info = "AsyncResourceHandler"
t=6010 [st=26]     -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=6010 [st=26]      CANCELLED
t=6010 [st=26]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                  --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=6010 [st=26]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=6010 [st=26] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Any idea why Chrome would force a redirect like that? I can't see anything wrong in the network tab, there is nothing coming back for that request.

More info:

Here is the Response Headers on a working Chrome browser.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, authorization, content-type, X-CSRF-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://api.domain.com
Content-Length:0
Server:Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be caused by an extension such as HTTPS everywhere or by Strict Transport Security (HSTS).

These factors are outside your control, to resolve it you need to modify the server-side API endpoint to serve CORS response headers, e.g.:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://api.domain.com
```

... or just enforce https side-wide. Then you don't need to worry about http/https origin violations. As a bonus, https has recently become one of the positive factors for your site's ranking on Google.

---

The log in the question clearly shows that HSTS is the culprit. <s>Chrome's HSTS implementation does not properly work with cross-origin requests at the moment ([crbug.com/387198](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=387198)). The only way for website owners to work around this bug is to enforce side-wide https, and access the API over https.</s>

f you want to reproduce the bug, visit `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and add the domain to the HSTS list via the first input box ("Add domain"). Then, after having reproduced the bug, remove the domain from the HSTS list via the second input box ("Delete domain"). This method is also a way for users to work around the bug. After all, if the domain is removed from the HSTS list, then there's no HSTS redirect any more.

**What is HSTS?**
HSTS is activated after the server sends a Strict-Transport-Security header in any of its https responses. After receiving this header once, the browser will force that all resources on the web page are requested over https. For more info, see http://chromium.org/sts and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security.

Since this bug occurs only for some of your users, it is most likely that that it is caused by a browser extension or some page on the API domain that responds with the STS header.

Comment: It's working on my machine, but not on my coworker's Chrome, I haved edited the question to show response from the server when it works.

Comment: Better comment: It's working on my machine, but not on my coworker's Chrome (but he can browse the website in standard HTTP mode), I have edited the question to show the response from the server when it works. Thanks, I will think about moving to an all HTTPS website.

Comment: @vincentp The log in your question clearly shows that HSTS is the culprit. Chrome's HSTS implementation does not properly support CORS at the moment. I've submitted a patch for that bug to Chromium 7 weeks ago, but the patch is still under review: https://codereview.chromium.org/348253002/. Until that patch is accepted, you cannot use CORS in combination with HSTS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have never heard of HSTS previously. I'm trying to go up the chain of events and understand why Chrome would think this domain/query is supposed to be done through HTTPS. Is this something defined for the domain at the web server level? We have a load balancer run by Nginx on top of everything taking care of SSL certificates and other things, can it be here?

Comment: Thanks again, I will dig into our configuration.